# Children sinning

Tags: practical-islam

If a children sins at the age of 12 but has some sign of puberty is his sins accountable. If did some sins such as disrespecting and saying bad words to parents will Allah forgive him? And some sins such as doubts and bad thoughts about Allah? And he feels that he brought those thoughts by himself?